# Xamarin Forms WebView disable autocomplete

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms `WebView` that loads a webpage using `Source = "myInternalSite.CompanySite.com"` that has an HTML input text field inside an HTML form.

Here is what is happening. A user types something in the input field and submits it. Then later they come back in and start typing again and a drop down appears on the input field with the last thing typed in.
(In chrome there is a setting *"Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click"* and in edge *"Save form entries"*)

**How can I disable auto fill for HTML forms in a Xamarin forms WebView?**

Or does this have to be done in the HTML

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how exactly you load a webpage. If you do something like this:

```
var browser = new WebView {
    Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

Then you are out of luck because you simply don't have control over HTML elements in a webpage that you are displaying.

However, if you are constructing webpage yourself like this:

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
    <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
    </body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

Then you can use those attributes to control the `autocomplete` feature:

```
<input autocomplete="off"/>
```

or

```
<textarea autocomplete="off"/>
```